# Как вставить символ в строку через каждых 4 символа в ней? Python

Tags: python

Всем здравствуйте, пишу программу на python, которая спрашивает у пользователя его номер карты, который я методом `replace` превращаю в строку с 16 элементами, хотелось бы через каждых 4 элемента вставлять пробел, чтобы номер был читабельнее
Как из `'1234123412341234'` получить `'1234 1234 1234 1234'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью срезов, например:

```py
number = '1234123412341234'
number_ = ' '.join(number[i*4:(i+1)*4] for i in range(4))
print(number_)
# 1234 1234 1234 1234
```

Answer (score 2):

Срезы и шаги с помощью `range`:

```
number = '1234123412341234'
step = 4
print(' '.join(number[i:i + step] for i in range(0, len(number), step)))
```

Comment: Кстати, да, всё время про `step` забываю

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

number = '1234' * 4
length = 4
res = ' '.join(map(''.join, zip_longest(*[iter(number)] * length)))
print(res)
```